# Why does my search query loop double on the second element?

Tags: php, loop, query

I'm writing a custom query for a wordpress loop that should match and filter elements into three categories 'premium', 'nachhaltig', 'guenstig'. I do that with a counting variable: $search_count.

At the second element the loop counts twice and the third element doesn't get a category, because the second element has two now.

The output is something like this:

- Element 1: count: 0 premium
- Element 2: count: 1 nachhaltig count: 2
  guenstig
- Element 3: count: 3 error (because the
  $search_classification doesn't have a third element)

This is my code:

```
$search_classification = array('premium', 'nachhaltig', 'guenstig');
/* add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'na_parse_request' ); */
add_action('pre_get_posts', function($query) {
    $is_search = $query->is_search && !is_admin();

    if ($is_search) {
        global $search_count;
        global $search_classification;

       
      
        echo "count: ";
        echo  $search_count;
        echo $search_classification[$search_count];

      
            $query->set('query_label', 'teamoutfit_product_tax_query');

            $tax_query = array();
            $tax_query[] = array(
                'taxonomy' => 'additional_classification',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => array($search_classification[$search_count]),
                'operator'=> 'IN'
            );


            $tax_query[] = array(
                'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => get_query_var('product_cat'),
                'operator' => 'IN'
            );

            $query->set('tax_query', $tax_query);
    
            $search_count++;
      
        
    }
});
```

If I change `'terms' => array($search_classification[$search_count])` to for example  `'terms' => 'nachhaltig'` the looping works correct with each Element getting the correct category.